# Running multiple instances of windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows forms application should be started multiple times when user clicks on the button inside the main form and he/she should be able to switch between running instances from application menu. Applications should be isolated from each other, so static classes and libraries should not be shared between instances.

One apparent way is to use separate processes, but it will be too heavy, may be I should use application domains,but there is no such sample in the net.
Can anyone suggest the best solution for this problem ?

Comment: Starting an application is by definition starting a new process. MSDN does have examples of how to run code in separate `AppDomain`s ([for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxx9f4c2(v=vs.110).aspx)). What level of isolation do you actually need here? If security is an issue, `AppDomain` sounds like your best bet (you would have trouble switching between process instances anyway). If not, then it seems like data structures that are instance-based instead of having static variables you don't want shared would be better.

Comment: thanks, the real problem is that application development is almost finished and modifying static structures into instance-based and testing again will take a long time.there is no security issue but I have to be sure ,that multiple app instances will not interfere each other.

Comment: Well, it's not like you can reasonably make a big change like running separate `AppDomain`s and just release the program without a significant amount of more testing either. Keep in mind that whatever you do now, you're likely to be stuck with for a long time to come. It won't take very long before good design costs you less in the long run than a hack now.

Comment: It's too urgent ,in the future I should redesign this rather old app anyway, but will appdomain separate my static structures? and can You suggest any sample of such kind?

Comment: Yes, `AppDomain`s are isolated from each other, including static members. I don't know what kind of sample you want other than that's in MSDN (see link in my first comment). You just execute code in an `AppDomain`, and there it is. You can execute the same code in different `AppDomain`s, and they all run independently. What more do you need? Or more specifically, having gone and looked at the examples that _are_ out there, what's missing from those examples that you need?

Comment: Running new instance is a relatively simple issue, but how can i get collection of all running instances and switch between them in my code ?

Comment: I recommend you research that, make an attempt, and then if you run into trouble, post a question that meets the community standards for being specific, narrow, and having a good code example to work from. That said, in general it ought to work the same as the multi-process scenario, though you'll have the opportunity to take advantage of cross-AppDomain data marshalling to communicate between the instances (`AppDomain`s are isolated from each other, but .NET will do marshaling for you with serializable types).